# ruby load file async?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, load

I have some weird issues going on (for a very weird use case as I'll explain).  I'm setting up a multi-tenant application using postgres schemas for data multi-tenancy.

Each `company` in my system will get its own schema.  The way I accomplish this is with an `after_commit` on the model, on create, that then goes and creates a new postgres schema, and loads `schema.rb` into it.  (copied from `rake db:schema:load` code) using ruby `load`.

You can see the gem [here](https://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment/tree/development)

Anyway, all this works (in the console).  Creating a company creates the new schema and i can switch to it etc...  my problem lies in my integration tests.  I have an rspec test that creates to companies like so:

```
before do
  @c1 = Factory :company
  @c2 = Factory :company
end
```

What's odd is that I start to get the logs about the db schema loading, but they're truncated.  Almost as if they're happening in parallel.  Here's a sample output:

```
>> create: database: unique_name1
-- create_table("first_table_in_schema_rb", {:force=>true})
>> create: database: unique_name2
```

`create: database` is my log line, the `-- create_table` is from `schema.rb` itself.

As you can see, the second `create: database` seems to happen while I'm loading `schema.rb` from the first company creation.

Does anyone know if `load` is somehow asynchronous?  I know ruby doesn't have real threads, but could it be using fibres or something?  This is really messing me up because when my test comes around, the postgres schema that was meant to be created doesn't seem to exist.

Rails 3.0.8
Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure this is your problem because im sure of what happens with `require` but not with `load`, the things this happen to me once with require because require is not atomic, so loading code from a file with require will cause a race condition. Maybe that is what is happening with load but i was not able to find any info about load been atomic or not.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind...  issue had nothing to do with `load` it was the fact that i was already connected to the `wrong schema` when importing the `schema.rb`

There was in fact an exception being thrown that was silently caught somewhere